# Passing arguments to a newly spawned terminal

Tags: bash, terminal, xterm

I am trying to automate some task at work. One of them is to run some aliases, one of which spawns a new terminal, an XTerm from a bash terminal.
Now after spawning this terminal, I would need to provide some more commands into this new terminal.

How can this be achieved. One method that I can think of is using expect scripts to handle those tasks. Would this work?
if not, are there any methods to run commands on the new terminal.

Edit:

Within the script I found this....

```
 execcmd="xterm -sb -sl 5000 -T "'`/usr/bin/hostname -s`.$LOADL_STEP_CLASS'" -e $path run_interactive $@
```

I think this is the one that spawns the new xterm out.. I need to run some commands on this script and then, get whatever it spits out on screen, looking for a particular string like for example "priority-level:" , rest would be simple regex doing the job for me, but I want to automate the interactions with this new xterm that spawned.

PS: I have no straight forward way of passing arguments to this terminal while spawning, without messing up with scripts that many other people are using. so I cannot modify the original alias, maybe write a wrapper around it somehow.

Comment: expect will not work because it cannot control GUIs (like xterm). Please show the current alias

Comment: Can you put the commands in the shell startup files?

Comment: I have edited the question, please have  a look again.

Comment: This is a programming question.  Generally you'd write (or reuse) an application running in the xterm accept the commands via a pipe or other *connection*.

Comment: I'd look at rewriting the workflow, not firing off unscriptable xterms would be one improvement.

Comment: agree with you @thrig , as it happens, it is legacy code there, and no one wants to touch it. it is just repetitive work typing in commands when you got a batch of task, I wanted to automate it, that's all. Still I will try on my part, as to what can be done. maybe pass a piggy back expect script that would do the interaction for me???

Comment: For the record:  I did not vote to migrate; I voted to close as unclear.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't that what the `-e *args*` flag to xterm is for? It's going to run whatever you feed it there,  so if you modify that argument so that the script or command it invokes also does the extra step you need,  you're done.

An alternative is to make the xterm shell a login shell so that your shell startup scripts are invoked, but that will have the side effect of invoking them for every login shell,  which might be be suitable in your environment.

Comment: What I need to feed it is not one command or a series of command, but an interactive session, where I run more commands and based on their outputs have to run other commands. so passing  an expect script to the be executed as parts of args would do the job?? also can you elaborate a bit more on your alternative.